How to display DOCX / XLSX in the browser while being on VPN-protected service
I'm working on an app in which I need an ability to quickly view sent attachments, usually xlsx/docx, but as far as I know MS365 Viewer and Google Docs viewer doesn't support URL-inline file streaming (like base64), and so via URL my files are not accessible due to VPN restrictions in my company.
Is there any way to overcome this?
PS. I'm on React client / nodejs server.
Thanks
